# Why is $\exists x \forall y \exists z \left(\left( y = x + z \right) \lor (z \leq x) \right)$ false?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I am trying to wrap my head around the proposition
$$\exists x \forall y \exists z \left(\left( y = x + z \right) \lor (z \leq x) \right),$$

where $x, y, z \in \Bbb N^+$.

The proposition is false, but I don't understand why. It is stated as

> There is a value $x$ which for every value $y$, there is a value $z$ such that ( =  + ) ∨ ( ≤ ),

so I started off with $(x,y,z) = (1,2,1)$, which is true.

Next, I tried $(x,y,z) = (1,3,2)$, which makes

**(3 = 1 + 2) ∨ (2 ≤ 1)**

**T ∨ F** = **T**.

I kept going, but I keep getting True.

Comment: There might be a typo. Perhaps they intended $\wedge$ instead of $\vee$ or some other variation. As written you can take $x=z=1$. Since $z\leq x$ is true for all $y$, the result of the $\vee$ is true too.

Comment: i checked to make sure, it wasn't a typo apparently

Comment: It's certainly true as written, and follows from the truth of $\exists x \exists z (z \le x)$ (just ignore the $y$ part entirely).

Comment: 1. Further to what has been said, a key point is that $∀y∃z(Pyz)$ logically implies $∀y∃z(Pyz∨Qz),\quad$ 2. Is the exercise perhaps asking whether the given formula is invalid (false in *some* interpretation)?

Answer (score 1):

$y$ can be any positive integer. Also, it says that there exists an $x$, so I can pick whatever $x$ I want. Pick $x=1$. Then $y=x+z$ is satisfied for $z=y-x$. However, $z$ must be a positive integer which is not the case only when $x \geq z $. The statement is clearly true.

Answer (score 0):

It's true since taking $z=x$ the right-hand side (wrt the $\lor$) of the statement $y=x+z \ \lor \ z \leq x$ is always true. It is surely a typo.